# How to install a local .deb file

Tags: debian, aptitude, maatkit

I'm trying to install the last version of maatkit in debian Lenny. I couldn't find a repository with the last version, so I got the .deb file.
The problem is How to I install this file?
man aptitude gave me no clues.

A repository would be the ideal solution.
bonus point if you know a repository with php 5.3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [dpkg](http://linuxreviews.org/man/dpkg/) directly.  The command *dpkg -i packagename* is what you probably want.

You could also install and use [gdebi-core](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/gdebi-core).  With it you can install a .deb package and also get the dependencies if you needed them.

Comment: Generally if dpkg fails and says you need some dependencies, you can grab them by running **apt-get -f install** if the dependencies are available in your repos.

Answer (score 4):

dpkg -i my_deb_file.deb